# Navigate to the page twice (jquery mobile bug ??)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I had a page with the simple jquery mobile codes like this.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
   $.mobile.navigate('/home');
});
```

When I load this page. Instead of only redirect to 'home' page, It redirects to 'home' page, then redirect back to this page, after that it redirects to 'home' again and end here. How to fix this issue ? Thanks.
Btw, if I set timeout for the navigate function 1 second for example, It'll work correctly. Don't really know why ?